# Break time, find any triple which matches pythagoras equation in O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm

I think it's interesting to solve this in holiday:

Given `n` integers, all of them within `1..n^3`, find if there is a triple which matches pythagoras equation in O(n^2).

As you know pythagoras equation is `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`. for example `3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2`.

As you know O(n^2 log n) is easy (with a little thinking), but will help to solve O(n^2). (space is not important).

**Edit:** As yi_H offered there is lookup table which can solve this problem easily, but for making it harder, space limit is O(n^2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, O(n) space: square all array elements, sort, for each z in the array use the classic linear-time algorithm to determine whether there exist x, y in the array such that x + y = z.

Comment: I like this idea.
No need hashes or any memory allocations at all - you can just run it in-place in your input array.
You might want to explain the "classic linear-time algorithm", though - I had not heard of that before, though it's easy to figure out if you think about it for a bit.

Comment: @Daniel Keep two array indices, one initially at the beginning and one initially at the end. If the sum of the elements at the current indices is too large, then the larger element cannot be involved in the solution – decrease the greater index. If the sum is too small, then the smaller element cannot be involved – increase the lesser index. Stop when the indices cross.

Comment: @Saeed Amiri Use the above O(n) algorithm n times (once for each z).

Answer (score 4):

All pythagorean triplets `(a,b,c)` have the following relation:

```
a = d * (2 * m * n)
b = d * (m^2 - n^2) 
c = d * (m^2 + n^2)
```

where

```
d >= 1  and  (m,n) = 1
```

(meaning: `m` and `n` have no comomn factor.

I guess one can find an algorithm to produce all triplets that are below `n^3` using this info.

Comment: +1 nice equations but still you have 3 different variables, (m,n,d).

Comment: @Saeed: I'm reading again your description. You have `n` integers that are in `1..n^3` range. The equations would be more helpful if you had ALL numbers in the `1..n^3` range.

Comment: @ypercube, I think you should develop with more detail your idea, I have a little complicated algorithmic way to solve this problem, but If you find a simple one with math it would be nice.

Comment: No, I think the @the guy formerly known as d has the best approach. Mine would work better if you had more numbers in the check-list, in the order of `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess O(n^2 log n) would be to sort the numbers, take any two pairs (O(n^2)) and see whether there is `c` in the number for which `c^2 = a^2 + b^2`. You can do the lookup for `c` with binary search, that's O(log(n)).

Now if space isn't an issue you can create a hash for all the values in O(n), then you can look up `c` in this hash with O(1), so it's going to be O(n^2). You can even create an lookup table for it since the numbers are between 1..n^2, so it's going to be a guaranteed O(1) lookup ;) You can also use a special lookup table which can do initialization, add and lookup in O(1).

Comment: Hash is good idea but searching in hash is amortized O(1), not all the times for any input.

Comment: Also hash may be cause to collision, it's depend on input size and the hash size you should to take, also creation of big hash (which prevent collision) may be cause bigger than O(n^2) time, I don't know should show this mathmatically.

Comment: if you choose the hash function to be the identity function you end up with a lookup table.

Comment: there are lookup tables with O(1) initialization, insert, search and delete. MIT Introduction to algorithms, Exercises 11.1-4 is an example for it. It's not really difficult, now it's your turn to think about it;)

Comment: hint from the book: "Use an additional stack, whose size is the number of keys actually stored in the dictionary, to help determine whether a given entry in the huge array is valid or not."

Comment: @yi_H, It seems to be nice i didn't have book right now, but if you have a link to that (or their name) it would be great, but I think they should have problem (like collision in hash).

Comment: +1 Thanks for new thing, but I'd edited again, may be you find another simple way.

Comment: I wonder now how you will make the problem even harder :D My current solution is the following: we only need lookup table for the square numbers, so with n^2 space you can have a lookup table for numbers up till n^4.

Comment: @Saeed Amiri, yi_H: actually, using an array of size n^(3/2), you can get O(n^2) [not armotorized, assuming O(1) `sqrt()` function]: just make an array of size n^(3/2), and set array[c]=true if and only if c^2 is in the original list. now, when you iterate over all pairs (a,b), just check if sqrt(a^2+b^2) is true or not.

Comment: you can even have a slow O(n) sqrt() function as there are only n numbers. it will still work.

Comment: @yi_H: It won't because you need to use `sqrt()` O(n^2) times [the number of possible pairs]

Comment: @yi_H, it can be done in O(n) space also I think about such a lookup and I think it needs O(n^3) space would you describe how you will create such a lookup wich works with O(n^2) space?

Comment: @amit, c^2 is not related to original list, would you describe your answer in detail (i.e as a new answer)?

Comment: @yi_H, if I change range of numbers from `1..n^3` to `1..n^100` it makes no difference it should be done in O(n^2) space and time, you try lookup if you learn me new thing I'll upvote another unrelated answer of you but, if you try to say that's currect without proof by just saying our book writes so, it's not really good answer and good way of thinking. it's not too hard to just use theorems.

Comment: This can be solved by results of Fermat diophantus problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem, Also it can be solved by a little multi level algorithmic way but I think if someone has a good idea, it would be nice.